# Is it possible to host views from mulitple threads in same region

Tags: wpf, prism

Is it possible to create views on different threads and add them to a region on the main ui thread?

I have got as far as I can but I am blocked by Prism trying to set the RegionManager attached property on the view, but this is called from the main ui thread, and therefore the call fails.

### UPDATE

The region is a WindowRegionAdapter so the views are hosted in different windows.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? I am asking because in a lot of cases there is a way around it.

Comment: I want to do this so I can have show a modal dialog for a given view and still work on all the other views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is generally not possible in WPF. Except for frozen [Freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx#inheritanceContinued)s, all your UI elements have to be created on the UI thread (i.e. the thread the window
was created on where you want to put the afore mentioned UI elments into).

You mentioned you want to do this because you want to display a modal dialog for a given view and still work on all the other views. You can achieve the same effect by displaying a modeless window and make it stay on top and disable the view that should become uneditable.

Comment: It is possible to have multiple UI threads see: http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/

Comment: Yes, but not within the same window, as I said: all your UI elements have to be created on the thread that the top level window was created on. Top level window being the window that you want to put the UI elements into.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, I have updated the question. I'm using a WindowRegionAdapter so the views are hosted in separated windows within the same region